# How could I know if the window is opened or not in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin

I use one layout in few cases. But when I show this layout in the window (com.vaadin.ui.Window) I have to hide one button otherwise layout stays unchanged. So I would like to know is the window opened or not at the moment. Is the any way to figure that out?

Answer (score 2):

with [`getWindows`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#getWindows%28%29) you get all the windows of an UI.  and with [`isAttached`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/AbstractClientConnector.html#isAttached%28%29) you will find out, if it is attached to the session (in a state where the user should see it)

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but maybe this helps:

```
public class MyLayout extends VerticalLayout {

    private Button myButton; // set it in the constructor

    @Override
    public void setParent(HasComponents parent) {
        super.setParent(parent);
        myButton.setVisible(!(parent instanceof Window)); // or recursively if need
    }

}
```